# TypeError: Cannot read property 'controller' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

The first time I navigate to a nested route, I get this exception, "TypeError: Cannot read property 'controller' of undefined"

It causes my app to not work correctly.  However, if I navigate around it starts working perfectly.

The below image shows the values of the variables and the line of code that throws has an undefined controller that causes the problems.  This code is part of the Ionic Framework.

**Click image to see full size**

[image: At Debug Breakpoint where exception occurs]

This is my only JavaScript file that defines the only module.

```js
angular.module("sa", ["ionic"])
    .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
            // hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
            // for form inputs)
            if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
                window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            }
            if (window.StatusBar) {
                // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
                window.StatusBar.styleDefault();
            }
        });
    })

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state("login", {
                url: "/login",
                templateUrl: "app/manager/login.html"
            })

            .state("manager", {
                abstract: true,
                url: "/manager",
                templateUrl: "app/manager/menu.html"
            })
            .state("manager.jobs", {
                url: "/jobs",
                views: {
                    "managerContent": {
                        templateUrl: "app/manager/requested-jobs.html"
                    }
                }
            })
            .state("manager.detail", {
                url: "/detail",
                views: {
                    "managerContent": {
                        templateUrl: "app/manager/requested-job-detail.html"
                    }
                }
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
});
```

This is the login.html that loads correctly.  It also allows the button to be clicked and navigate.

```html
<ion-view view-title="Login" >

  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-light"></ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-content class="has-header" >
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item href="#/manager/jobs">
        Manager
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

This is the side menu file.

```html
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">

  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-light">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left"> 
        <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>

      <ion-nav-view name="managerContent"></ion-nav-view>

    </ion-nav-bar>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">

    <ion-header-bar class="bar-assertive">
      <span class="title">Cluber</span>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item class="item-icon-right" menu-close ui-sref="login">
          <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right icon-accessory"></i>Logout
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>

  </ion-side-menu>

</ion-side-menus>
```

This is the file that gets loaded into the menu content when naviaged to.

```html
<ion-view view-title="Dashboard">
  <ion-content has-bouncing has-header="true">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="item-border item-icon-right" ui-sref="manager.detail">
        Clean Apartment
        <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right icon-accessory"></i>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="item-border item-icon-right" ui-sref="manager.detail">
        Repair Side Walk 
        <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right icon-accessory"></i>
      </ion-item>

    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

This is the simplest example I have that always reproduces the JavaScript exception.  Again, this only happens the first time the that "manager.jobs" is navigated to.

Comment: You could use `debug` to check value of `enteringHeaderBar` before call `enteringHeaderBar.controller`.

Comment: Looks like `enteringHeaderBar` is undefined.

Comment: Yes, enteringHeaderBar is undefined.  This value is calculated two lines above the error.

Comment: I haven't used ionic, I'm guessing this javascript is auto generated? I ask because in the image, 2 lines above your highlight it looks as if `enteringHeaderBar = undefined;` .

Comment: That's probably the debug output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the below line of HTML in the menu.html file.  I had this nested inside the `<ion-nav-bar>`, instead it is required to be a direct descendent of `<ion-side-menu-content>`.

```html
 <ion-nav-view name="managerContent"></ion-nav-view>
```

Answer (score -1):

`self.isInitialized` is actually `false`, which will set `enteringHeaderBar` to `null` (two lines above your highlighted one).

You're setting `self.isInitialized` to `true` at the end of the function. That's the reason why it fails the first time, but then works (in the next update it is true and `enteringHeaderBar` will be set to `getOffscreenHeaderBar()`.

Comment: Yes I agree.  Unfortunately the code in the image is from the Ionic framework, apologies for not making this clear.  I can't edit their code.  Thank you for the information.

Comment: Oh, okay. But why is this the accepted answer then? :)

Comment: I'm new to StackOverflow.  I changed the accepted answer to the above answer.